# Add a gap between jstree nodes text and scrollbars

Tags: jquery, html, css, jstree

I have a simple jstree in a container that is smaller than the tree:

```
<div style="width:250px;height:150px; border:solid; overflow: auto;">
  <div id="jstree" style="padding:20px"></div>
</div>
```

see demo at [plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/VIFRq9kSShPtHU2tKfF1?p=preview)

I am trying to add a visual space (ie of 5px) between the visible portion of the node's text and the scrollbars. so that there is a gap between the end of a chopped line and the vertical scrollbar and the chopped lines have '..' in the end, and a gap between the bottom of the tree and the horizontal scrollbar.

I have looked at many posts here and tried various combinations of padding, margins, wrapping divs etc but no success.

The solution I am looking for is:

- ideally css only
- adds a gap between the visible portion of the node's text and both the horizontal and the vertical scrollbar
- adds ellipsis to truncated node's text
- works with [jquery.scrollbar](https://github.com/gromo/jquery.scrollbar)

thx!

Comment: plunkr demo looks fine...

Comment: yea got it... add `.jstree-anchor{
  margin-right:5px;
}` to css file

Comment: since the gap is 5px  you are not noticing the difference change 5px to 50px

Comment: for me it is giving margin.. I am on chrome... https://plnkr.co/edit/TS6iPDbS8xXboGP3ffuW?p=preview

Comment: ah I guess i failed to understand your question... do you mean you have to  give margin to visible portion of text?

Comment: i donno whether this is what you are looking for... this is not a direct solution but a workaround... kindly check https://jsfiddle.net/RRR0308/jfu845zr/  is this what you are looking for?

Comment: I have just placed a absolute positioned div of width 10px... it will give an effect of 10px margin... I donno whether we can do what you require just by styling existing elements... did you check the link which i posted in prev comment?

Comment: great ! Is it possible to style your xyz class without fixed values for height/top/left ?

Comment: maybe by the help of jQuery we can dynamically set the height/width

Comment: can't the 'bar' be somehow floated to the right of the tree ?

Comment: bt bar do you mean `scrollbar'? if yes then its not possible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I understood that you're trying to add ellipsis before the text be overflowed by div. Accordingly to scrollbars movement, the text would be showing.

Basically, I add a calculation after the plugin triggers the `ready.jstree` event.

```
$('#jstree').on('ready.jstree', function() {
    resizeWrap();
});
```

Please, check my complete solution:
https://jsfiddle.net/alexndreazevedo/qozdy7m8/

Comment: Your solution looks nice to see but I think @koffius is looking for a different outlook. Your css make the area change size as we open and close each node of the tree. This in turn means that the effect of having hidden results depending on a scrollbar will never even be allowed to happen thus eliminating every chance of having a padding-effect.

Comment: I like this solution the most and will give it the bounty. The height problem can be easily fixed by setting a fixed height on the div. I still don't get a gap before the scrollbar but at least I get the elipsis which is nice. alexndreazevedo, if you fix the height and gap issue I will mark this as the answer, thx!

Comment: @kofifus, I changed the function. Case your content is major than fixed size of wrapper, it calculates a minor width to expose the content, simulating the padding. Please, see the link and check my answer :)

https://jsfiddle.net/alexndreazevedo/qozdy7m8/

Comment: this is really good thx ! can you please add a gap before the bottom horizontal scrollbar ? then it will be a complete answer

Answer (score 4):

Hi here is a workaround for this issue... kindly check https://jsfiddle.net/RRR0308/jfu845zr/ ... I have inserted a absolute positioned div into main div and have set the height and width so that it gives the effect of 10px margin.

**HTML**

```
<div style="width:250px;height:150px; border:solid; overflow: auto;">
      <div id="jstree" style="padding:20px"></div>
      <div class="xyz"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.xyz{
  position:absolute;
  height:133px;
  width:10px;
  background:#F3F5F6;
  z-index:999;
  top:11px;
  left:235px;

}
```

Updated Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/RRR0308/jfu845zr/3

Comment: kindly check https://jsfiddle.net/RRR0308/jfu845zr/1/ ... I am changing height and left dynamically using jQuery

Comment: Updated : https://jsfiddle.net/RRR0308/jfu845zr/2/  I have fixed top issue too... now the xyz div will always be inside the main div

Comment: Updated: https://jsfiddle.net/RRR0308/jfu845zr/3/  this will set the top and left position of  `xyz` div inside the main div even if window is resized or div is floated

Answer (score 0):

This adds a gap between the visible portion of the node's text and both the horizontal and the vertical scrollbar (`5px` added).

It also adds an ellipsis to the truncated node's text.

```
.jstree-anchor {
    width: 150px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    margin-right: 5px;
}
```

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/VIFRq9kSShPtHU2tKfF1?p=preview
add the above css in css section.

Comment: ? I don't see any gap or elipsis

Comment: add the above css in the style.css section

Comment: hey sams, it doesn't work, and your plunkr doesn't work, downvoted

Comment: Cool, have you done the below steps
1) open your plunker code provided
2) click on the style.css and add the provided css in that
3) run again
4) can you see the ellipses added and a space between the text and scroll 5px
5) for horizontal scroll you need to add